# Describe the push forward of the borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ under its Cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability-theory

Will the push forward be the borel probability measure on [0,1]. If so, how to show this?

Kindly help

Comment: It will be uniform. i checked using examples but i m not able to prove in general.

Answer (score 0):

It wont be uniform in general when the distribution has discontinuities. As you can see inverse image $(\mu(F^{-1}((-\inf, x])))$ remains the same when moving in between discontinuity in the image (i.e., if u is the point of discontinuity the inverse image stays same for $F^+(u)\leq x \geq F^-(u))$ and hence the resulting distribution will maintain a constant value in this range and hence cant be $F_1(x)=x.$

For F continuous, yes it is uniform.

The resulting distribution is:
$$
F_1(x) = \mu(F^{-1}((-\inf , x ])) $$ $$= \lim_{\epsilon \to  0} F(\sup\{ u : F(u) \leq x \} - \epsilon) + I(F(\sup\{ u : F(u) \leq x \}) \leq x) 
\mu(\sup\{ u : F(u) \leq x \})
$$